# Differentiation in Higher Dimension

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose, $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:E\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is said to be differentiable at $x\in E$ if there exist a linear transformation $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ such that, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah|}{|h|}=0$.

Instead of this, can we defined differentiablity in the following way?

We will say, there exist a continuous function $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $A(th)=tA(h)$ for scalar $t$ and satisfying $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah|}{|h|}=0.$

Will this make sense?

Comment: Presumably, that last $Ah$ is meant to be $A(h)$.

Answer (score 1):

That would be some other kind of derivative since it's not necessarily linear in $h$. I think that what you define is the [Gateaux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative) while the former is the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative).